# Selecting a text in word-addin Officejs that comes right before a searched text

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

```
var foundItems = context.document.body.search('here', { matchCase: false, matchWholeWord: true })
```

If I have a paragraph saying, "I am stuck here.". I need to read the word that comes before the searched word, in this case it is "stuck". How can I do that?

Comment: See if the [LocationRelation](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/word/word.locationrelation) and related APIs can help. It's used in this sample: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Word-Add-in-Angular2-StyleChecker

Comment: I am curious why there is such a need? I am afraid so far there is no direct way to do this. One tricky way to try is after you get the searched range, you can call range.paragraphs.getFirst().split() to split into range collection by using "space" delimiters. And then go through the collection to locate the searched result index. then the previous index is what you want.